# Mostrar imagen creada en Imageview

Tags: imagen, canvas

Hola tengo una situacion tengo un canvas en el que se genera un dibujo y necesito posteriormente a que se genera insertarlo en un imageview dentro de otro formulario. este es el codigo que tengo para generar el dibujo.

```
Btn_Siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            lienzo.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            //attempt to save
            String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(), lienzo.getDrawingCache(),
                    "mario" + ".png", "drawing");
            if (imgSaved != null) {
                Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "¡Dibujo salvado en la galeria!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                savedToast.show();
             

            } else {
                Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "¡Error! La imagen no ha podido ser salvada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                unsavedToast.show();
            }
            lienzo.destroyDrawingCache();
        }



    });
```